# nuget encodes the blank spaces in names of files

Tags: powershell, nuget, nuget-package

I created a nuget package using the pack command:

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference#Pack_Command

everything works fine; the only issue that I have is related to the fact that I'm trying to install a certificate through a powershell script. The name of this certificate is something like "CompanyName Ltd.pfx" (note the blank space) but in the nuget package it is encoded as "CompanyName%20Ltd.pfx" and therefore my installation script fails for this certificate. Now, this is a minor issue as I can modify the certificate name removing the blank space, but anyway I'm wondering if there is a method that prevents (or controls) this type of encoding (as I haven't found anything in the nuget documentation).

Comment: I respond to myself; the problem is related to the fact that I'm unzipping the files using a zipping tool (freebyte) that obviously doesn't decode the special characters for blank spaces. If I use the install command provided by nuget (http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference#Install_Command) the problem is resolved as the the install command actually extracts the package files in the output location taking care of the decoding process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. Unzipping the file does seem to encode the file names no matter what utility you use.

I solved this by opening the .nupkg in the [NuGet Package Explorer](https://npe.codeplex.com/) and using **Export** from the File-menu.